# How to use django timezone.now() for the client user

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building a journal app, and would like to check if a user posted an entry yesterday when they log in. If they didn't, I'd like to redirect them to the entry page. Here's the code I'm using in my views:

```
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        YESTERDAY = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)
        try:
            yesterdays_entry = Entry.objects.get(user=self.request.user, date=YESTERDAY)
        except Entry.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('entry_create_page')
```

In settings.py, I have this set:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_TZ = True
```

The issue I'm having is when it's checking the time, it's using UTC not the logged in user's timezone. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your question doesn't clear enough! @brenden

Comment: I assume you mean **"it's using UTC not the default TIME_ZONE".**  If you want to use the logged in user's tz, you will need to use [`activate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate).

Comment: Thanks, that pushes me in the right direction. I was actually saying it was using UTC not the user's timezone, which is also TIME_ZONE. But regardless, activate helps. But for activate, I'd need to know what the user's time zone is. Is the best way to use middleware for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the date in the configured time zone. For that use `timezone.localdate()` instead of `timezone.now()`. Now since it is very likely that your `date` field in your `Entry` model is a `DateField` please check that you are assigning the correct local date when saving the entry.